# How to require multiple permission group membership for file access?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

Given that users can be added to multiple groups, I'm in a situation where I need to restrict access to an intersection of groups rather than a union or subset of groups for a file.

More concretely, given permission group `A` and group `B`, I'd like to restrict access to users who are members of `A` **and** `B`, and not members of `A`-only or `B`-only. Current ACL usage allows you to restrict access to users who belong to `A` **or** `B` by adding to the ACL of a file.

The closest I've considered is some kind of nested directory scheme `/dir_A/subdir_B/file`. Here `dir_A` directory has execute-only permissions for `A` and `subdir_B` has execute-only permissions for `B`, and file has read-only permissions ACLs for `A` and `B`. As I understand this only prevents listing files and does not stop a user with only group `A` membership of reading the file given the full file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACLs only complicate the situation, so for this question ignore them.

Given this:

```
drwx--x---  userC  groupA  directory_A
drwxr-x---  userC  groupB  directory_A/directory_B
```

The contents of `directory_B` can be accessed by only `userC` and users that are in *both* `group_A` and `group_B`.

Anyone in only one of the groups (other than `ownerC`) will be blocked by one directory or the other.

This sounds like what you proposed, so I don't see why you say it "*does not stop a user with only group A membership of reading the file given the full file path*".

Comment: Thanks Ray — looks like I misunderstood how permissions propagated through directory structures. I do believe this solves my issue.